# failure to input data into sql table using java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, servlets

i have been having this problem for the past 3 days. I can read from my SQL table and read info but can't input/update data into my tables(InBound table,OutBound table) in the SQL database. The program runs fine but just no input to the tables.

here is the code:

ResponsiveText.java

```
public class ResponsiveText extends HttpServlet {
    DetailsDTO edto = new DetailsDTO();
    IOBoundDTO iodto = new IOBoundDTO();

    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String body = request.getParameter("Body");
        String fromNum = request.getParameter("From");
        String message, lisc;
        int len = body.length(), nrc = Integer.parseInt(body);

        edto.setNrc(nrc);
        edto.setNumber(fromNum);
        iodto.setNumber(fromNum);
        iodto.setNrc(nrc);

        //input details of sender into inbound table 
        InBoundDAO.Send(iodto);

        if (body.matches(".*\\d.*") && (len == 9)) {
            // numbers are in the body

            //gets details of license status
            LicenseDAO.Send(edto);

            switch (edto.getLice()) {
                case 0:
                    lisc = "Dear " + edto.getName() + ", your License has already been proccesed and been picked up";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    lisc = "Dear " + edto.getName() + ", your License is ready, please come pick it up at the RATSA office";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    lisc = "Dear " + edto.getName() + ", your License is not yet ready, please be patient";
                    break;
                default:
                    lisc = "There is no License available with this NRC number, Please contact our RASTA offices for enquiries";
                    break;
            }

            message = lisc;

        } else {
            // if numbers are not in the body
            message = "Please enter your 9 NRC digits";
        }

        // Create a TwiML response and add message.
        TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
        Message sms = new Message(message);

        try {
            twiml.append(sms);

            //input data into outbound table when message is sent
            OutBoundDAO.Send(iodto);

        } catch (TwiMLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.setContentType("application/xml");
        response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXML());
    }
}
```

InBoundDAO.java

```
public class InBoundDAO {

    public static boolean Send(IOBoundDTO dto) {

        boolean status = false;

        try {
            Connection c = DB.connect();

            PreparedStatement psmt = c.prepareStatement("insert into inbound values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat yr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");//get current year
            DateFormat mth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");//get current month
            DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");//get current date

            psmt.setInt(1, 0);
            psmt.setString(2, dto.getNumber());//inputting phone number
            psmt.setInt(3, dto.getNrc());//inputting NRC number
            psmt.setString(4, dt.format(date));//inputs current year
            psmt.setString(5, mth.format(date));//inputs current month
            psmt.setString(6, yr.format(date));//inputs current date
            psmt.executeUpdate();

            psmt.close();
            c.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            System.out.println("IOBpundDAO Error: " + ex);
        }

        return status;

    }
}
```

DetailsDTO and IOBoundDTO are just getters and setters

Comment: Have you debugged it? Does it go through the `psmt.executeUpdate();` line, without an exception?

Comment: Yes. It goes through with out a problem

Comment: When I try through a void main it works fine